# There is an easy way to connect Moto X on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-4.4-kitkat, ubuntu-13.10, mtp

I bought a Moto X recently, and i'm trying to access his files on linux using mtp, I've found some ways, but all have many steps and don't work.

There is not an easy way to connect Moto X on linux?

**EDIT**

I'm using ubuntu 13.10, and i don't have access to a wifi connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nautilus from Ubuntu 14.04 already have support to mtp, I only did an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use SCP. This app has it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.vx.connectbot&hl=en

Comment: Scp is very simple to use. `scp /file/on/computer ip_addressofphone:/location/on/phone`

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if this is what you are looking for:

I installed the free SSHDroid, ran the app and ssh'ed in as in
`ssh -p 2222 root@192.168.0.113`.